# How to get maximum number of concurrent events in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timespan

I have a table named `events` like this:

```
id: int
source_id: int
start_datetime: timestamp
end_datetime: timestamp
```

These events could have overlaps, and I want to know maximum number of overlapping events that have occurred over a time span. For example, in a situation like this:

```
id | source_id | start_datetime     | end_datetime
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | 23        | 2017-1-1T10:20:00  | 2017-1-1T10:40:00
1  | 42        | 2017-1-1T10:30:00  | 2017-1-1T10:35:00
1  | 11        | 2017-1-1T10:37:00  | 2017-1-1T10:50:00
```

The answer is 2, because at most 2 events overlap at 10:30 until 10:35.
I'm using Postgres 9.6

Comment: a time span is an input?

Comment: for the sake of simplicity, consider it constant for each query

Comment: I don't know if it makes that much of differrence, but consider it 9.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the idea:  count the number of starts and subtract the number of stops.  That gives the net amount at each time.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
with e as (
      select start_datetime as dte, 1 as inc
      from events
      union all
      select end_datetime as dte, -1 as inc
      from events
     )
select max(concurrent)
from (select dte, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as concurrent
      from e
      group by dte
     ) e;
```

The subquery shows the number of overlapping events at each time.

You can get the time frame as:

```
select dte, next_dte, concurrent
from (select dte, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as concurrent,
             lead(dte) over (partition by dte) as next_dte
      from e
      group by dte
     ) e
order by concurrent desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: In the windows function, do we have a default `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`?

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey . . . I think the default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` when `ORDER BY` is specified.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: don't you need to make group by dte in the last query?

Comment: @pure_true . . . Yes, in the subquery.  Good catch.

Comment: @GordonLinoff cool, then might not it work the way as it suppose to work for cases when dte are identical? I am asking cause I have used your perfect algorithm, but due to grouping it does not increment correctly when we have the same dte.

Comment: @pure_true . . . It should still work.  However, it might depend on whether you consider the end date as part of the period or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For the part that gets the time frame, you have `lead(dte) over (partition by dte) as next_dte`, but it just returns nulls for end times. I think it's supposed to be `lead(dte) over (order by dte) as next_dte`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure how the `id` and `source_id` column should be treated, but from your description, something like that maybe:

```
select e1.source_id, 
       count(distinct e2.source_id) as overlap_count, 
       array_agg(e2.source_id) as overlap_events
from events e1
  join events e2 
    on e1.source_id <> e2.source_id
   and (e1.start_datetime, e1.end_datetime) overlaps (e2.start_datetime, e2.end_datetime) 
group by e1.source_id
order by overlap_count desc;
```

Given your sample data, that returns the following:

```
source_id | overlap_count | overlap_events
----------+---------------+---------------
       23 |             2 | {42,11}       
       11 |             1 | {23}          
       42 |             1 | {23}
```

To only get the maximum row, you could add a `limit 1` to the query.

Another (probably slower) option, if you need the complete row from the events table:

```
select e1.id, e1.source_id, e1.start_datetime, e1.end_datetime, 
       (select count(*)
        from events e2
        where e2.source_id <> e1.source_id
          and (e1.start_datetime, e1.end_datetime) overlaps (e2.start_datetime, e2.end_datetime)
       )  as overlap_count
from events e1
order by overlap_count desc;
```

---

Another option is to use [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) and the `&&` operator instead of `overlaps`:

```
select e1.source_id, 
       count(distinct e2.source_id) as overlap_count, 
       array_agg(e2.source_id) as overlap_events
from events e1
  join events e2 on e1.source_id <> e2.source_id
             and tsrange(e1.start_datetime, e1.end_datetime,'[]') && tsrange(e2.start_datetime, e2.end_datetime, '[]') 
group by e1.source_id
order by overlap_count desc;
```

Comment: An event can overlap many others but if they all are disjunctive max number of concurrent events will be 2.